# Encoding Csv (cp1252) on Mac not working well

Tags: python, macos, csv, encoding

I'm trying to encode csv file to read this character " **ü** "

On my windows laptop, it worked with no issue, but on my macbook instead of ü i got ÿ

after i checked for other special characters, they aren't correct too

When i encode using Atom Text Editor (Windows 1252), it encodes correctly (like on my windows laptop), but when i encode using my python script i got it wrong

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


with open(r'mastermp.csv', encoding='cp1252') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            line_count += 1
        else:
            line_count += 1
```

CSV File:
[image: CSV FILE]

Comment: macos may not understand/support `cp1252` which is a Windows code page. Can you create this file using some other more universal encoding, like `utf-8`?

Comment: utf-8 can't decode this character : ü

Comment: What is actually in the file? (hexdump it)

Comment: what do u mean by hexdump it, i didn't understand very well @wildplasser

Comment: Hexump is a (ms-dos) program to show the actual contents of a file in hexadecimal representation. In unices you could use `od` , or its derivatives.